# Unable to install php_pgsql in AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: php, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to connect to RDS instance from EB. But I am getting this nasty error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()
```

I tried to install php_pgsql by creating packages.config file in .ebextensions folder with following content.

```
packages:
    yum:
        php56-pgsql: []
    commands:
        01-install-pglib:
            command: "yum install -y postgresql94-libs"
        02-install-pg:
            command: "yum install -y php56-pgsql"
        03-install-pg:
            command: "service httpd restart"
```

But it is not working. Is there any way to install pg client for PHP in ElasticBeanstalk.

Comment: I think you need to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.php) to connect to RDS PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by following commands.

```
container_commands: 
  110-remove-pg: 
    command: "yum remove -y php56-pgsql"
  120-install-pglib: 
    command: "yum install -y postgresql94-libs"
  130-install-pg: 
    command: "yum install -y php56-pgsql"
```

Hope it helps someone.